# processes started in this session

Tags: bash, process

I've opened a terminal session and started some processes with `&`. When I tried closing the terminal window, it warned me that there were still jobs running in the background.

I can see the processes running with `ps`, but how can I know which ones were started through this session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `jobs -l`
>   
>        Lists process IDs of the active jobs

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find all the background processes started from the current `bash` session, you can use the `jobs` builtin of `bash`.

From `help jobs`:

> ```
> jobs: jobs [-lnprs] [jobspec ...] or jobs -x command [args]
> Display status of jobs.
>
> Lists the active jobs.  JOBSPEC restricts output to that job.
> Without options, the status of all active jobs is displayed.
> ```

On the other hand if you want to find all the processes that were started from this `bash` session, you can use the `$$` variable of `bash` which will give you the PID of the current `bash` instance. Then you can parse the output of `ps -ef` command to find all the processes whose parent process ID (PPID) is `$$`:

```
ps -ef | grep -P "^[^ ]+\s+[^ ]+\s+$$\s"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `ps -auxf` to see which shells the background processes are children of.